# json object vs array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I'm querying a remote server and receiving a json reponse. The format of the reponse depends on the number of objects in the response. If there is a single object it looks similar to:

```
"results": {
  "meeting": {
    "location": "Location A",
    "time": "1378033200"
  }
}
```

But if there is more then one object in the response, I get an array of objects instead:

```
"results": {
  "meeting": [
    {
      "location": "Location A",
      "time": "1378033200"
    },
    {
      "location": "Location B",
      "time": "1379250000"
    }
  ]
}
```

The complete response from the server includes a "count" variable, so I can distinguish between the two situations. In my Javascript at the moment I first check the count, and if there is exactly one object, I read out the location and time information similar to:

```
var location = results.meeting.location;
var time = results.meeting.time;
```

If there is anything other than exactly one object, I do

```
for(var i=0; i<count; i++) {
  var location = results.meeting[i].location;
  var time = results.meeting[i].time;
}
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of handling the two situations?

Comment: Can you alter the JSON response? That would be the most elegant way.

Comment: Yep, your parsing code is fine. I would change the JSON to always be an array.

Comment: I agree with @YotamOmer. `meeting` should always be an array, even if you only have one or even zero items in it. This will save you a lot of trouble, because you don't have to distinguish betweet two possiblities. It's also the more consistent way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs - I agree, but unfortunately I cannot change the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always you can loop it as an array,

```
if(!(results.meeting instanceof Array)){
   results.meeting = [results.meeting];
}
```

So you will get always an array , if one an array with one data

So and after always

```
var count = results.meeting.length;
for(var i=0; i<count; i++) {
  var location = results.meeting[i].location;
  var time = results.meeting[i].time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this situation is to change your JSON response so that `meeting` is always an array, even if it only has one entry. If you aren't able to update the way the JSON is being created, a simple way is to test using `instanceof`:

```
if(results.meeting instanceof Array) {
    //array
} else {
   //object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var meetings = result.count ? result.meeting : [result.meeting];
```

But the better overall design certainly is to always return an array in the first place.